# NullPointerException when using UDF in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions, udf

I have a DataFrame in Spark such as this one:

```
var df = List(
  (1,"{NUM.0002}*{NUM.0003}"),
  (2,"{NUM.0004}+{NUM.0003}"),
  (3,"END(6)"),
  (4,"END(4)")
).toDF("CODE", "VALUE")

+----+---------------------+
|CODE|                VALUE|
+----+---------------------+
|   1|{NUM.0002}*{NUM.0003}|
|   2|{NUM.0004}+{NUM.0003}|
|   3|               END(6)|
|   4|               END(4)|
+----+---------------------+
```

My task is to iterate through the VALUE column and do the following: check if there is a substring such as {NUM.XXXX}, get the XXXX number, get the row where $"CODE" === XXXX, and replace the {NUM.XXX} substring with the VALUE string in that row.

I would like the dataframe to look like this in the end:

```
+----+--------------------+
|CODE|               VALUE|
+----+--------------------+
|   1|END(4)+END(6)*END(6)|
|   2|       END(4)+END(6)|
|   3|              END(6)|
|   4|              END(4)|
+----+--------------------+
```

This is the best I've come up with:

```
val process = udf((ln: String) => {
  var newln = ln
  while(newln contains "{NUM."){
    var num = newln.slice(newln.indexOf("{")+5, newln.indexOf("}")).toInt 
    var new_value = df.where($"CODE" === num).head.getAs[String](1)
    newln = newln.replace(newln.slice(newln.indexOf("{"),newln.indexOf("}")+1), new_value)
  }
  newln
})

var df2 = df.withColumn("VALUE", when('VALUE contains "{NUM.",process('VALUE)).otherwise('VALUE))
```

Unfortunately, I get a NullPointerException when I try to filter/select/save `df2`, and no error when I just show `df2`. I believe the error appears when I access the DataFrame `df` within the UDF, but I need to access it every iteration, so I can't pass it as an input. Also, I've tried saving a copy of `df` inside the UDF but I don't know how to do that. What can I do here?

Any suggestions to improve the algorithm are very welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something which works but not very optimized I think. I actually do recursive joins on the initial DataFrame to replace the NUMs by END. Here is the code :

```
    case class Data(code: Long, value: String)

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()

        val data = Seq(
            Data(1,"{NUM.0002}*{NUM.0003}"),
            Data(2,"{NUM.0004}+{NUM.0003}"),
            Data(3,"END(6)"),
            Data(4,"END(4)"),
            Data(5,"{NUM.0002}")
        )

        val initialDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data)
        val endDF = initialDF.filter(!(col("value") contains "{NUM"))
        val numDF = initialDF.filter(col("value") contains "{NUM")

        val resultDF = endDF.union(replaceNumByEnd(initialDF, numDF))
        resultDF.show(false)
    }


    val parseNumUdf = udf((value: String) => {
        if (value.contains("{NUM")) {
            val regex = """.*?\{NUM\.(\d+)\}.*""".r
            value match {
                case regex(code) => code.toLong
            }
        } else {
            -1L
        }
    })

    val replaceUdf = udf((value: String, replacement: String) => {
        val regex = """\{NUM\.(\d+)\}""".r
        regex.replaceFirstIn(value, replacement)
    })

    def replaceNumByEnd(initialDF: DataFrame, currentDF: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
        if (currentDF.count() == 0) {
            currentDF
        } else {
            val numDFWithCode = currentDF
                .withColumn("num_code", parseNumUdf(col("value")))
                .withColumnRenamed("code", "code_original")
                .withColumnRenamed("value", "value_original")

            val joinedDF = numDFWithCode.join(initialDF, numDFWithCode("num_code") === initialDF("code"))

            val replacedDF = joinedDF.withColumn("value_replaced", replaceUdf(col("value_original"), col("value")))

            val nextDF = replacedDF.select(col("code_original").as("code"), col("value_replaced").as("value"))

            val endDF = nextDF.filter(!(col("value") contains "{NUM"))
            val numDF = nextDF.filter(col("value") contains "{NUM")

            endDF.union(replaceNumByEnd(initialDF, numDF))
        }
    }
```

If you need more explanation, don't hesitate.